# Write Notification object to Parcel

Tags: android, android-notifications

How do I have to store a Notification object to retrieve it later?

I am creating a library to handle GCM messages and want to allow who uses it to create a custom notification to use it instead of the default one, which I create.

Any ideas? Notification is not serializable and I don't know if a parcel can be used to store a notification object to use it when receiving the Push from GCM

Thanks in advance